# Get derived (generic) class members from base class (or shared interface) reference

Tags: c#

I am struggling to formulate my question properly, I hope I can clarify it through the following description:

I have an abstract generic base class that is supposed to describe a specific container item, upon other things, and another abstract class of the same name to reference the generic classes by. I also created an interface to reference them by, both work but still result in the same issue eventually. For this example i am using the shared base class

```
public abstract class ItemEditorState
{
}
```

and the derived generic class

```
public abstract class ItemEditorState<T> : ItemEditorState where T : Item
{
    public abstract SimpleDatabase<T> Items { get; set; }
    
    public abstract void DoStuff();
    ...
}
```

So far so good.

Now I have classes deriving from `ItemEditorState<T>` corresponding to different Items.

```
public class EditorStateItemA : ItemEditorState<ItemA>
{
    private ItemADatabase _itemADatabase; //ItemADatabase is public class ItemADatabase : SimpleDatabase<ItemA> {}

    public override SimpleDatabase<ItemA> Items { get => _itemADatabase; set => _itemADatabase = value; }
    
    public override void DoStuff(){}
    ...
}
```

So far so good again.

Now I have a static manager class holding a `List<ItemEditorState>` of references to all `ItemEditorStates`, such as `EditorStateItemA`, `EditorStateItemB` etc.

```
public static class ItemEditorStateManager
{
    public static List<ItemEditorState> itemEditorStates = new List<ItemEditorState>();

    public int GetState(int index) => itemEditorStates[index];
}
```

But since I reference the derived class instances by the shared abstract base class (or in another case  the `IItemEditorState` interface), I can't access any members.

What I would like to do is access the `Items` list of any  of `EditorStateItemA` or `EditorStateItemB` within the list in the `ItemEditorStateManager`from the `ItemEditorStateManager.GetState(index)` method.

I know I would probably have to cast it to the proper class first, but I don't know the specific type at that point. I am sure my architecture is off, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Declare `ItemEditorStateManager` with a generic parameter

Comment: @Charlieface I am not sure how I would make that work, since there is only supposed to exist a single ``ItemEditorStateManager`` that should provide static access to the list of ``EditorItemState<T>``-derived references.

Such as that

``var state = ItemEditorStateManager.GetItem(index);``

should give me the an instance which i can access the 'items' member of.

Comment: Ok, then I think you would have to declare `T` on `ItemEditorState` to be covariant (or is it contravariant`) and move the declaration